# How to best expose methods in WinForm?

Tags: c#, web-services, tcp

I have a C# form application that connects to a electronic device using the serial port.
The class "'SerialCommunicationManager'"  hooks up to the serial port on application startup and handles the dirty business of talkning to the device.

What I would like is to expose the following methods.

- Write()
- SerialDataReceived event
- SerialDataTransmitted event

Primarily a local website running on the same machine is the one I want to expose the methods for, but in the future I imagine the need for external applications as well.

**What is the easiest way to expose the functionality?**

- TCPIP client server?
- Web service? (Can I create a web service inside a WinForm?)
- other?

Big thanks

//David

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the context; you start with Windows Forms and end with websites. I don't get this.

Comment: The Form application is connected to a electronic device. I want other applications (such as a website) to be able to see the status of the device as well as sending commands to it. The big question is: How do I allow other applications to talk to the device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend [self-hosting a WCF Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158.aspx).  This provides you a huge amount of flexibility in terms of how you serve and expose this information, including being able to change the method by which its served via configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, that if you would like to do it properly, you should break apart your forms app, and create:

- a service that handles serial comm and has an API exposed through remoting
- a Forms app that uses the API and makes a way with the service

Then, depending on the locality of your web site, if it will remain local (or near local - LAN):

- web site should use remoting to call the service

else, if you plan to have multiple web sites:

- web service hosted inside the IIS that will wrap remoting API
- web site that will use web service

However, if it is too much work to do - just use remoting and expose needed methods to the web site.

Answer (score 1):

In a recent project we did the following:

- Write a Console application (or Windows Service, depending on your needs) that communicates with the electronic device.
- Make the Console application host a .NET 4 WCF service.
- Write a .NET 2 Windows Forms application to communicate through Web Services with the console application.

In this context, I could imagine the website you are mentioning to also use Web Services (WSDL) to communicate with the Console application.